# xpath query xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an input xml as below

```
<maindocument>
<first>
<testing>random text</testing>
<checking>random test</checking>
</first>
<testing>
<testing>sample</testing>
<checking>welcome</checking>
<import>
<downloading>valuable text</downloading>
</import>
</testing>
</maindocument>
```

The output here i want the same output like below

```
<maindocument>
<import>
<doctype>Valuable</doctype>
<docint>text</docint>
</import>
</maindocument
```

I am trying for the above code in xslt With the help of absolute path and relative path my question is how i will get into testing element then i have to select import element from there.

Please guide me

Regards
Karthic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With the help of absolute path and relative path my question is how i will get into testing element then i have to select import element from there.
```

Actually, there is no need to specify a complete path to `testing` and check that it has an `import` child.

The XSLT processing model (**[built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)**), combined with your templates and proper template match patterns, does the navigation for you.

The built-in templates are selected for execution if there is no explicit template that matches a particular node. he cumulative result of applying the built-in templates is that the document tree is traversed and only text nodes are output.

One can specify templates to override the built-in ones only for nodes that should be processed in a different, specific way. When the built-in templates apply templates for a child of a node and there is explicit (user-provided) template matching that node, this explicit template is selected for execution/processing of that node.

**This short XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <maindocument>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </maindocument>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="import/downloading">
  <import>
    <doctype><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')"/></doctype>
    <docint><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/></docint>
  </import>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XMLdocument**:

```
<maindocument>
    <first>
        <testing>random text</testing>
        <checking>random test</checking>
    </first>
    <testing>
        <testing>sample</testing>
        <checking>welcome</checking>
        <import>
            <downloading>valuable text</downloading>
        </import>
    </testing>
</maindocument>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<maindocument>
   <import>
      <doctype>valuable</doctype>
      <docint>text</docint>
   </import>
</maindocument>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well copying the right elements to the output is easy, and with XSLT 2.0 it is also easy to break up the contents of the `downloading` element:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="maindocument">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="testing/import"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="import">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="import/downloading">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w)(\w+)\s+(\w+)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <doctype>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(regex-group(1)), regex-group(2))"/>
      </doctype>
      <docint>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
      </docint>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using Saxon 9.4 the above stylesheet transforms the input

```
<maindocument>
<first>
<testing>random text</testing>
<checking>random test</checking>
</first>
<testing>
<testing>sample</testing>
<checking>welcome</checking>
<import>
<downloading>valuable text</downloading>
</import>
</testing>
</maindocument>
```

into

```
<maindocument>
   <import>
      <doctype>Valuable</doctype>
      <docint>text</docint>
   </import>
</maindocument>
```

The use of `analyze-string` is meant as an example, it is not clear to me from your sample what kind of input the `downloading` element can have and how you want to handle that. So post more details if the above is not sufficient.